# Cordova camera saveToPhotoAlbum not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I tried to save a photo in the Photo Library but its still not working. Well I get ''error: Error capturing image'' on console, and no visible picture in the library.

This is my code:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function($scope, $cordovaCamera){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onGetPictureSuccess, onGetPictureFail, { 
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
    function onGetPictureSuccess(imageURI) {
        console.log("success: " + imageURI);
    }
    function onGetPictureFail(message) {
        console.log("error: " + message);
    }
});
```

and my config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name></name>
    <description>
    </description>
    <author email="" href="">

    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="~0.8.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="~5.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="~1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.2.0" />
</widget>
```

I need to save the photo at a location where the gallery both of Android and iOS can find it. I have to say, that I am not very familiar with the development of a cordova application, and thats why I think I missed some tiny piece of knowledge which would clarify this.

I've stumbled upon a memory problem behaviour of Android which closes and opens apps. I can only use a very slow emulated device, could that be a problem?

Most of the Q/As here for this specific problem didn't help me, maybe I still missed something but I am working on this for hours and its driving me a little crazy..

regards

Comment: As far as I am concerned I "solved" this Problem with saving and moving the taken file and exculding the option saveToPhotoAlbum.

Comment: Damn, I didn't know that there was a timelimit for editing... I forgot to mention that the original Problem still exist. I still want to move the file somewhere, where the gallery can find it (possibly platform independent). And the option saveToPhotoAlbum still throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

**SaveImage** 
This plugin allows you to save local JPEG image files to the iOS Camera Roll/Photo Library or Android Gallery. Other image mime types are currently not supported. The image file to be saved to the Library/Gallery must be available on the device.

> The plugin is based on code seen in several other existing plugins:
>           Canvas2ImagePlugin (https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin) by
>           Tommy-Carlos Williams (https://github.com/devgeeks) ImgDownloader
>           (https://github.com/Nomia/ImgDownloader) by "Nomia"
>           (https://github.com/Nomia)
>               cordova-camera-roll (https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-camera-roll) by Max Lynch
>           (https://github.com/mlynch)

Thanks to all of the above mentioned authors for sharing their code openly.

```
        cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-save-image
```